# linux mint debian edition artifacts

Tags: debian, linux-mint

I just booted from a live usb the latest version of linux mint debian edition (the x64 version.)
I see some strange artifacts on my desktop.(It occurs on bot cinnamon and mate);
There are some vertical lines moving and changing their color and the desktop has a right "decal" style.
This behavior starts at system boot.
As you can see the mouse points where the right hand side of the desktop ends.
Anyone here with the same problem?
[image]

Comment: We're going to need more information about your graphics hardware. that is very strange, I have been using LMDE happily for a while now with no problems.

Comment: I have an asus notebook with a Intel Core™ i3 3217U, Graphic: Intel integrated HD Graphics 4000 . Full specs here: [asus website](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/S56CA/#specifications); I also tried the x32/x64 cinnamon, mate and XFCE versions. All have the same issue.

Comment: And this does not happen with other OSes? Is it OK in the BIOS screen? When you say the problem starts at boot, when exactly do you mean? Is the bootloader (GRUB) OK?

Comment: So, I used different ubuntu-based distros and everything works ok (including mint cinnamon/mate). Windows is also fine. After the system has booted from the usb (I already said is the LIVE version), anything that is written on the screen after I press "start linux mint"(the first option from the boot menu) has this graphic issue. Should I try to install the OS and perform a full update?

Comment: Can't really say. It _sounds_ like a driver problem that will be fixed by the full update/proprietory driver. I'd go ahead and try it yes.

Comment: I am unable to perform the installation. The system freezes after the desired partitions are specified